# Remove unused JS, CSS, PHP, images/files from server

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

Are there any tools out there which are able to scan all your server files or your `www` folder (localhost) and tell you:

- which CSS ids and/or classes aren't used
- which JS functions are not called, ever
- same thing, but for PHP methods or variables
- which images or even html files are not linked to

Is there anything that does this? Or at least some of the above?

Comment: You could run xenu and compare to a directory dump

Comment: This is impossible, due to the dynamic nature of JavaScript.  Arbitrary code can be executed, and you cannot know what functions are in use, and where.  It's impossible to determine which resources are not linked to, as you might have links to them outside your site.  If you can limit the scope of your problem, you will have more success.

Comment: He is asking for methods and variables not used, not only files not used. Good question, I dont think it is possible (think about variable valiables and variable functions), but who knows.

Comment: Obviously it would be impossible for such a tool to identify with an accuracy of 100%, due to the dynamic aspects you've mentioned. But I was referring to something like, if it finds a method, and no reference to that method, then flag it. And regarding the resources, scan the code in a "static way" and flag the resources that are not linked directly and then let me interpret if they are or are not. There MUST be SOMETHING out there :( isn't there?

Comment: YSlow is telling you what css classes are not used, but that is always based on the current page. For Javascript a possible but non totally valid way might be writing testcases for each feature on your page. Everything not highlighted in codecoverage might at least be worth to look over

Comment: audit section of chrome developer tools can make you see of unused css on the page but not to rely because this will show you for the current page.

Comment: Hei guys, John, MatthiasLaug, Jai, write these comments as answers, they deserve at least a one up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an addin for Firefox called CSS Usage which will list the selectors used. I haven't used it for a while, but I think it also lists unused selectors.

I don't know of anything that will fulfil the remainder of your requirements.

Comment: @AndreiBogdan Would you like to post the answer?

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about the comment previous to that regarding the Firefox extension :)